# Performing SSL pinning on Alamofire5?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to implement SSL pinning with Alamofire 5 and I ran into an issue during implementation.
I am unable to call AFsession.request as method: .post is being considered as an extra parameter.
I have attached my code below.

Session :

```
final class AFsession {
    let evaluators = [
        "mydomain.com":
            PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator(certificates: [
                Certificates.stackExchange
                ])
    ]
    let session: Session
    private init() {
        session = Session(
            serverTrustManager: ServerTrustManager(evaluators: evaluators)
        )
    }
    private static let shared = AFsession()

static func request(_ convertible: URLRequestConvertible) -> DataRequest {
        return shared.session.request(convertible)
    }
}


struct Certificates {
static let stackExchange =
    Certificates.certificate(filename: "mycert")

private static func certificate(filename: String) -> SecCertificate {
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "cer")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
    let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, data as CFData)!

    return certificate
    }
}
```

implementation :

```
AF.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: [:], encoding: body, headers: header)
        .responseString { response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                print("error calling POST on \(URL)")
                print(response.result.error!)
                return
```

There error is in the request parameters. method:.post is seen as an extra parameter.
EDIT : using the Standard Implementation of AF.request works without issue
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Session` you created with a `ServerTrustManager` to make your requests, it will not work with `AF.request`.

Comment: Like i mentioned in the question, i am unable to call it from the session. That’s where I got my error. It says method : .post is additional